# Cassandra - Schema for chat application

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am working on a chat application schema on Cassandra, would like to get some advice on how I can improve this further.

Here are my queries:

- get user's room by user id ordered by last reply time
- get messages by room id order by timestamp
- get participants by room id

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  user_id bigint,
  nickname text,
  email text,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE messages(
  message_id timeuuid,
  room_id timeuuid,
  author_id bigint,
  time_bucket int,
  content text,
  PRIMARY KEY((room_id, time_bucket), message_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC);

CREATE TABLE rooms(
  room_id timeuuid,
  room_name text,
  status text,
  creator_id bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY(room_id)
);

CREATE TABLE room_users(
  room_id timeuuid,
  user_id bigint,
  last_reply_time timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY((room_id), user_id)
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW room_users_by_user_id AS
  SELECT *
    FROM room_users
    WHERE room_id IS NOT NULL
    AND user_id IS NOT NULL
    AND last_reply_time IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id), last_reply_time, room_id)
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (last_reply_time DESC);
```

I can get user's room by user id ordered by last reply time like so:

```
SELECT * FROM room_users_by_user_id WHERE user = 1;
```

I can get messages by room id like so:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE room_id = 1;
```

I can get participants by room id like so:

```
SELECT * FROM room_users WHERE room_id = 1;
```

One of the downsides of this design is that when there are new message for room 1, I have to first get a list of `user_id` from `room_users` and update the `last_reply_time` for each row using `IN` statement.

If there are 100 users in the room, I will have to update 100 rows for each new message in the room. I understand that the write speed for Cassandra is exceptionally fast, but are there any more efficient ways to achieve the same result?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `last_reply_time`? Is that simply the time for the last message?

Comment: One comment: stay away of materialized views, thay are marked as experimental and they are not production ready.

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson `last_reply_time` is just the timestamp of the last message, so that when a users in in the room list view, I can get all rooms ordered by the `last_reply_time`

Comment: @Horia Thanks for the comment, this is also something I am not sure about, because manually updating related tables seems inefficient and fragile. What would be the best practice on making sure data are synced across tables other than using materialized view?

Comment: @colloque Then you should move `last_reply_time` to rooms table. The client should keep track of what rooms a user belongs to and update it's cache whenever a user joins/leaves a room. I believe this should solve your problem.

Comment: @colloque how you solve your problem? In my case, I have a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64167601/how-do-i-sort-a-table-with-frequently-updated-information). In my case, each chat room has the latest message. This information is always changing. In cases of change, I want to put the chat room at the top of the list. Classic behavior in many messengers. To achieve this behavior, I have to recreate an entry in the table. That is, delete the record and create it again, but with updated data. I think this is inefficient